# How to open a .FIC file?

Tags: database, file, windev

I want to read a .fic but always ask me a password that I never set... 
The question is simple, anyone know how to open the file? 
I´m trying to use Windev without successfull results

Comment: Have you tried to open it using Pervasive SQL clients?

Comment: I had installed it the last Friday but I really don´t know where can I find the function to open it because it request me a server

Answer (score 0):

In the database description of your project you can set a password for each tables when you apply the changes. If you modify a column and apply the changes to the deployed data you can specify the new password or disable the password in the wizard.

In addition the software [Hyper File Password Recovery Tool](http://www.syscode.fr/?p=50) can recover the password, for Windev 15 at least.

Comment: Did u test that software? It request me an executable, not the fic file.

Comment: No, I didn't try it